# Getting metadata from a jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatable, datatables

I have a table marked up in Razor, which I turn into a [`DataTable`](https://datatables.net/) after rendering it. It looks something like:

```
<table id="customerViewList" class="table grid-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomerName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomerCategoryName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PrimaryContact)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerCategoryName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrimaryContact)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
@section viewScripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/datatables.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // All DataTables should be initialised, hence the class based selector.
            $(".grid-table").DataTable();
        });
    </script>
}
```

It works well as a DataTable: columns are orderable, the rows nicely paged, and the 'grid' is searchable, but when I mine through all its objects properties, I can find nothing telling me which table column corresponds to which property in each data row. I'm starting to suspect the table is purely positional, so when I say:

```
select two, one
```

The value of property 'two' will appear in the first column and that of 'one' in the second. Is there anybody that knows Datatables and can point me to a place where it tells me "column one is for the 'two' property...." etc.

Or much I maintain this myself?

Comment: If I understand you correct : When you initialise a DOM table as you are doing above, then the table is "_purely positional_" i.e data is inserted as is, if you not have any fancy column renderers. Use a JSON source if you want explicit binding.

Comment: I know full well that pure DOM is only positional, but as I stated, I am running a plugin on the table, and it adds a lot of functionality, a lot more than I mentioned when I described adding it. 

It could easily scan a data row and apply metadata from the row properties to the table columns. In fact, your table only needs to be an empty div and it will create columns and headings, and populate with HTML data.

Comment: ..."_but as I stated, I am running a plugin on the table,_" , yes you are using jQuery dataTables ....

Comment: As @davidkonrad is trying to explain to you, if you apply the `DataTable` function to a fully-rendered HTML table, as in this case, then you will not get the functionality that you are looking for.  If you use an empty div (I generally use an empty table in a div), you can specify a JSON source for the data option.  When you do this, you can also specify which data go in which column, and you can find that later as well.

Comment: Thank you, @BobRodes, I will look at that approach. I need to render JSON anyway for the column 'definitions'. Problem is, it makes the HTML much less readable, but maybe I can comment what is going down.

Comment: If you use a JSON object for your data, all you need for html is `<table id="whatever"></table>`.  Seems pretty readable to me.  :)  You can specify everything else as options in the `DataTable` function.

Comment: @RobRodes, but looking at the HTML, you can't see table columns, and looking at the JS you can't see the HTML around the table. Anyway, I'm also using the empty table option now.